# Auto-complete doesn't work on Chrome or Edge

Tags: autocomplete, passwords

Autocomplete off does not work on Chrome or Edge browsers. I can avoid for username but auto-complete off doesn't work for password

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" autocomplete="off" aria-autocomplete="both" aria-haspopup="false" onfocus="this.removeAttribute('readonly');"
               onblur="this.setAttribute('readonly', true);">
        <br>
        <label for="password">Password: &nbsp;</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" autocomplete="off" aria-autocomplete="both" aria-haspopup="false" onfocus="this.removeAttribute('readonly');"
               onblur="this.setAttribute('readonly', true);">
```